# Unwanted space in actionbar after updating Sdk to 24

Tags: android, android-actionbar, margin, padding

How can I remove the margin(or padding) between title and icon? It's not toolbar. It's support actionbar.

Comment: Found any solution over this?
Post the answer pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually a fix to ensure the Toolbar aligns with the [material design keylines](https://material.google.com/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-baseline-grids), specifically the `72dp` margin between the left edge and the toolbar/action bar title.

Comment: So how can I remove it?

Comment: The Support Library seeks to match the material design guidelines exactly, you'll have to use something else if you want to specifically break those guidelines.

Comment: How? /: There is at least some way to get the toolbar title view, @ianhanniballake ?